# Does changenotifierprovider get dispose on navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

I initialise `Provider` on Page of app:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>

...
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2(context: context)),
```

But when I Navigator.push page to Page2:

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {

final context;

  Page2({Key key, this.context});
...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
MaterialApp(
home: Scaffold(
…
```

It give error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
>   Consumer Widget

How I can fix this error?

Comment: No. But they are scoped. Only its descendants can access it.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for reply! But is `Page2` not descendant because I am use `Navigator` to push onto route?

Comment: Exactly. The Navigator is an ancestor of your provider. So you need to either add the provider in both routes, or move the provider above Navigator

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks! But I am confuse. I was think I can use `Consumer`  in Page2 to get provider. because Page1 is before Page2. You can give example?

Comment: Page2 is not a descendant of Page1. They are in different branches of the widget tree.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Oh. So when I have many page in app they are all in separate widget tree and only common ancestor is `materialapp`?

Comment: Yes, and everything you put above MaterialApp.